# How to run Completable from a loop inside of Callable?

Tags: java, android, rx-java2

I need to save a data class having tree structure into database. Since I don't have to reflect any results on UI I'm choosing Completable. The first `mergeWith` works fine when I'm creating a parent. I can see created tables with data for Parent and Kid.

Then I need to create a list of grandchildren for each `Kid` but I don't see any logs for `createGrandchildren` and no data in the DB. I tried using `mergeArray` and `flatMapIterable` but couldn't succeed.

Of course I could create all the instances in one Completable but each instance can be created separately.

```
    private Completable runCompletableFromCallable(String s, Callable<Object> callable) {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        return Completable.fromCallable(callable).doOnComplete(
                () -> LOGGER.info(s + " took: {} mSec", (System.currentTimeMillis() - start)));
    }

    public Completable createParent(@Nonnull final Parent parent) {
        return runCompletableFromCallable("createParent", () -> {
            mParentDao.create(parent);
            return parent;
         // This works fine
        }).mergeWith(createKids(parent));
    }

    private Completable createKids(final Parent parent) {
        return runCompletableFromCallable("createKids", () -> {
            Collection<Kid> kids = parent.getKids();
            if (kids != null) {
                for (Kid kid : kids) {
                    kid.setParent(testPlan);
                    mKidDao.create(kid);
                    // The issue: grandchildren never created
                    createGrandchildren(kid);
                }
            }
            return kids;
        });
    }

    private Completable createGrandchildren(final Kid kid) {
        return runCompletableFromCallable("createConfigurations", () -> {
            Collection<Grandchild> grandchildren = kid.getGrandchildren();
            if (grandchildren != null) {
                for (Grandchild grandchild : grandchildren) {
                    grandchild.setKid(kid);
                    mGrandchildDao.create(grandchild);
                    // And so on.
                    createToysOrSmthElse(grandchild);
                }
            }
            return grandchildren;
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a solution. I just got to use `Observable`.

```
...

    private <T> Observable<T> runObservableFromCallable(String opName, Callable<T> callable) {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        return Observable.fromCallable(callable)
                         .doOnComplete(() -> LOGGER
                                 .info(opName + " took: {} mSec", (System.currentTimeMillis() - start)));
    }

    public Completable createParent(@Nonnull final Parent parent) {
        return runObservableFromCallable("createParent", () -> {
            mParentDao.create(parent);
            return parent;
        }).flatMapCompletable(this::createKids);
    }

    private Completable createKids(final Parent parent) {
        return runObservableFromCallable("createKids", () -> {
            Collection<Kid> kids = parent.getKids();
            if (kids != null) {
                for (Kid kid : kids) {
                    kid.setParent(testPlan);
                    mKidDao.create(kid);
                }
            }
            return kids;
        }).flatMapIterable(kids -> kids).flatMapCompletable(this:: createGrandchildren);
    }
...
```